# android we chat SDK -cannot find the way to get image of user

Tags: android, wechat

I need to implement we chat in the app. Register app, login and share works fine - but cannot find the way to get user profile using android sdk.

Thank you for any useful info.

Answer (score 0):

I am also searching so same thing and found a link

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/

may be it help for you

Comment: There is no weChat sdk integration on the example you sent. (We chat - Chinese social network -  https://www.wechat.com/en/) .

Anyway thanks for response.